# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzbqo()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp;

Tags: java, android

This is the error I’m getting:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzbqo()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.example.akash.firedemo-Tniw8sNtmq6E7zMSOD54YQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source:128)
    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source:22)
    at com.example.akash.firedemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upgrade libraries.
Firstly, in **project** level `build.gradle` file, add the following:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

Then, in **module** level `build.gradle` file, add the following:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.1'
```